# How can we transpose a Table in Spotfire with keeping columnames as rownames?

Tags: r, spotfire

My sample data is like below. However the original data is very large so I can not hardcode.

```
+-----+-------+---------+
| IDN | NAME  |  VALUE  |
+-----+-------+---------+
| 121 | test  | 1254.25 |
| 152 | testa | 1585.25 |
| 587 | testb | 5878.69 |
+-----+-------+---------+
```

After transpose function:-

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|   121   |   152   |   587   |
+---------+---------+---------+
| test    | testa   | testb   |
| 1254.25 | 1585.25 | 5878.69 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Expected:-

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|  IDN  |   121   |   152   |   587   |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| NAME  | test    | testa   | testb   |
| VALUE | 1254.25 | 1585.25 | 5878.69 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I was using t() function is spotfire but in the resultant data table I am missing the columnnames as rownames. Are there anyways to keep

Comment: Did that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with UnPivot and Pivot.

- Insert > Transformation
- Add the Unpivot with the settings below and hit ok
- Add the Pivot with the settings below
- Change the column name for column 1 with Edit > Column properties

[image: UnPivot]

[image: Pivot]

**Here Is The Data Table Settings**

```
    Add the transformations:
        a. Unpivot
            Add columns to pass through:
                IDN
            Add columns to transform:
                NAME
                VALUE
            Category column name: Column
            Select category column data type: String
            Value column name: Value
            Select value column data type: String
            Select 'Include null values'
        b. Pivot
            Choose row identifiers:
                Column
            Choose value columns and aggregation methods:
                Concatenate(Value)
            Choose column titles:
                IDN
            Column naming pattern: %M(%V) for %C
```